# Views, get data for parent term as well

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I will try to keep the question simple and short. I have (Drupal 7):

a Vocabulary "Country regions" (depth 1 level):
Austria
-Burgenland
-Tyrol
Belgium
-Arlon
-Liege
-Namur
...

a Content type "Regional development programs" with a "Applies to:" field on this vocabulary, a terms multi-select field.

a View with an URL argument (a region) - contextual filter.

I'm trying to build a View to show all "Regional development programs" that use the parent of the given region.

Example: 
URL: /get-programs/Liege/
I want to retrieve all programs that apply to Liege (given argument), which is easy, BUT I also need all programs that apply to the region parent, which is Belgium (because, of course, all Belgium programs apply to its regions as well).

Sorry if the solution is already given in another question, but I couldn't find a similar question (I found several questions for getting the children of an argument, but not for the parent).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your problem would be solved by adding a relationship to your view. Here are the steps:

1. Add Relationship: taxonomy terms on node
2. Select the vocabulary you want to use.
3. Add Relationship: parent term

Now you should be able to add fields from any of the terms or their parents, and to use them as contextual filters as well.