# Display multiple parent Terms of hierarchical Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm running a Drupal7 installation and have a view where I want to list all parent terms for the chosen child terms of a node. I tried the [solution described for this Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40274/views-get-data-for-parent-term-as-well) but can't make it work like I want to display multiple parent terms as well.

For a taxonomy like

```
parent1
-child1.1
-child1.2
parent2
-child2.1
-child2.2
```

and 2 Nodes with the first having child1.1, child1.2, child2.1 and the second having child2.2 selected the view should display

```
Node1Title
parent1 parent2

Node2Title
parent2
```

I'm grateful for any hints.